# how to get local storage token in vue methods property

Tags: vue.js

i've a vue app which requires a token when sending a request each time i try to send a request i keep getting token  not defined... here's the error

[image]

this how i call my methods property in script tag

```
<script>
import { mapActions } from "vuex";
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  name: "Products",
  data() {
    return {
      addresses: [],
      products: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onDeleteAddress(id, index) {
      axios
        .delete(`http://localhost:5000/api/addresses/${this.$route.params.id}`,
          {
            headers: {
              Authorization: "Bearer" + token,
              "x-access-token": token
            }
          }
        )
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

this my vue template

```
 <a href="#" @click="onDeleteAddress(address._id)">Delete</a>
```

this works in my mounted life cycle hook but when i input it in my methods component i get an error

```
 const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
```

please how can i get the token stored in my local storage and define it in my vue methods conponent

Answer (score 1):

In first make sure the item is already stored in the localstorage
Second instead of calling it from the localstorage it is better to define it in main.js file as global variable so you can use it free every where
Example

```
Vue.prototype.$globalData = Vue.observable({ token: localStorage.getItem("token") });
```

And now you can use it in your methods like this

```
this.$globalData.token
```

You can as much as you want variable in the globalData object